# How to receive an int through an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am passing an int through an Intent but I do not know how to receive it because I have to receive an intent from the OnCreate method but if I place it there I can't compare it to another int in the rest of the code:
                                                                                                                   Here I am sending the Intent:

```
public class HomeActivityPro extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText conttext = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.texthome );
Button buttone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttone);
String maxom = conttext.getText().toString();
int maxam = Integer.parseInt(maxom);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_home);

    View.OnClickListener maxim = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {
            Intent wall = new Intent(HomeActivityPro.this, GuessOne.class);
            wall.putExtra("maxPressed", maxam);
            startActivity(wall);
        }
    };
    buttone.setOnClickListener(maxim);
```

Here I receive it:

```
public class GuessOne extends ActionBarActivity {
    int randone;
    int contone;
    Bundle bundle;
    int maxnumpre = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_guess_one);
    Intent wall = getIntent();
    int maxnumpre = wall.getIntExtra("maxPressed", 0);}
```

But after the onCreate method I have to do this:

```
if (contone >= maxnumpre ){
            resultaone.setText("You Failed" + " " + maxnumpre);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

Comment: App is crashing yet you haven't posted a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the data passed inside `onCreate` method not in the declaration.

Also you are not sending a `Bundle`, you are sending a `String` in the `Intent`. So you need to get the `String` from the `Intent`.

Do it like this

```
public class GuessOne extends ActionBarActivity {
    int randone;
    int contone;
    Bundle bundle;
    String maxPressed = "";
    int maxcont = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_guess_one);

        maxPressed = getIntent().getStringExtra("maxNumberPressed");
        try {
            maxCont = Integer.parseInt(maxPressed);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    //the rest of the code
```

Also send data like this

```
Intent wall = new Intent(HomeActivityPro.this, GuessOne.class);
wall.putExtra("maxNumberPressed", conttext.getText().toString());
startActivity(wall);
```

Comment: Are you sending integer in the intent??

Comment: Please see my edited answer. And use this to send data in intent `wall.putExtra("maxNumberPressed", conttext.getText().toString());`

Comment: Is the text in the EditText an integer??

Comment: Such as? I would guess 1, 2 ,50, 40 etc. Right?

Comment: You need to put some checks if you are sending correct value. If the value is not integer then you will get the error. before sending the value check if its not null. If it is null then send some default value such as 0